# Vega-Lite tooltip not showing time in UTC

Tags: javascript, timezone, data-visualization, vega-lite, vega

I have a Vega-Lite spec visualizing timeseries data with ISO8601 UTC timestamps. These show correctly on the X-axis labels, but in tooltip the time is displayed in local timezone, not UTC.

Is there a way to set timezone for the tooltip?

```
"tooltip": [
      {
        "type": "quantitative",
        "field": "data[1]",
        "title": "Value "
      },
      {
        "type": "temporal",
        "field": "data[0]",
        "title": "Datetime ",
        "format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ"
      }
    ]
```

[Link to full spec in Vega editor](https://vega.github.io/editor/#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)

Comment: Not sure if it's the correct way or not, but it does seem to allow `"scale": {"type": "utc"},` in the tooltip item, despite the text editor highlighting it as yellow.  Also, it may be possible to do this with a calculated field, but not sure exactly how.  (I don't use Vega myself.)

Comment: I think this is a bug; I've reported it here: https://github.com/vega/vega-lite/issues/7185